# v-data-table: separate into independent components

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuetify, vue-cli

Стокнулся с проблемой при использовании Vutify. V-Data-Table работает как 1 компонент вместе со всеми фильтрами, сортировкой и пагинацией. В моем случае сортировкка, таблица, поиск и пагинация - это отдельные компоненты.
Проблема заключается в том, я не совсем понимаю как и какие Props нужно передать в мои компоненты.

Возможно сущетсвует более лакничный способ решения этой проблемы?

Заранее Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего компонент таблицы должен предоставлять EventBus или же содержать слоты для вставки кастомных фильтром и реагировать на определенные емиты this.$emit(‘set-pagination’, 1)
Думаю как-то так )